# Recibir y Enviar Parámetros a Programa ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce

Se tienen dos aplicativos Windows C#, y se pretende enviar parámetros del  primero al segundo.

El **segundo**, el cual recibirá los parámetros utiliza tecnología ClickOnce por 
 lo que al instalar en la maquina no se crea un ejecutable .exe sino una 
 instancia con la extención "miprograma.appref-ms" y es indispensable enviar los 
 parametros a esta instancia.

El programa que recibe los parámetros se inicializa de esta manera:

```
static class Program  
{  
  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string [] parametros)  
  {  
    MessageBox.Show(parámetros[0].toString()); // Mensaje de Prueba para validar recepción de parametro  
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);  
    Application.Run(new Form1());  
  }  
}
```

El **primer** programa encargado de llamar y enviar los parámetros lo hace de la
 siguiente manera:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();  
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Ejemplo\\miPrograma.appref-ms";  
startInfo.Arguments = "ParametroPrueba";  
Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Sin embargo al ejecutar de esta manera no recibe el parámetro, confirmandolo con
 el mensaje de prueba(Este mensaje `MessageBox.Show(parámetros[0].toString()`)).

Cabe destacar que si genero el ejecutable ".exe" y hago el llamado mostrado anteriormente funciona de manera correcta, sin embargo requiero hacer el llamado al programa generado por el clickonce con la extensión ".appref-ms".

Encontré una manera de ejecutar desde el **explorador de archivos** de Windows
 colocando la siguiente ruta `C:\Ejemplo\miPrograma.appref-ms ParametroPrueba`

De esta manera el me abre el segundo programa y me muestra el mensaje de 
 confirmación(`MessageBox.Show(parámetros[0].toString())`), según lo esperado.

Sin embargo si intento colocar esta ruta con el parámetro ya definido desde el 
 llamado del programa, me indica que el archivo no existe, generando un error.

Adjunto ejemplo del llamado con la modificación (el cual genera el error)

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();  
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Ejemplo\\miPrograma.appref-ms ParametroPrueba";  
Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las aplicaciones ClickOnce no reciben los parametros en el `main` como el resto de aplicaciones. En su lugar, debes obtenerlos de la propiedad `ActivationArguments`(`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData`). Prueba el siguiente código:

```
string[] activationData;
if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments != null)
{
    activationData =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;
    if (activationData != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(activationData[0])=;
    }
}
```

En este enlace tienes una información mas amplia:[How to pass arguments to an offline ClickOnce application](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/)

Comment: Excelente, la modificación sugerida por **Pikoh** es correcta y completamente funcional.  Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Ahora comparto la prueba funcional realizada gracias al comentario de Pikoh. **Primer** programa que hace el llamado y envió de parámetros al **Segundo**.

Evento:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();  
  startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\MiUsuario\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Prueba\\Prueba.appref-ms";  
  startInfo.Arguments = "Parametro1;Parametro2;Parametro3";  
  Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);  
}
```

Mientras que el método definido en la clase Program de la solución del programa que recibe los parámetros es el siguiente:

```
static class Program
{
  /// <summary>
  /// The main entry point for the application.
  /// </summary>
  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
    try 
    {
      string[] activationData;

      if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments != null)
      {
        activationData = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData;

        if (activationData != null && activationData.Length > 0)
        {
          String[] arregloParametros = activationData[0].Split(';');

          // Cliclo solo de prueba para mostrar los parametros enviados
          for (int i = 0; i < arregloParametros.Length; i++)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Parametro: " + arregloParametros[i]);
          }

          //Abrir ventana solo si cargo parametros
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        else
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Parametros no Cargados");
        }
      }  
      else
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Parametros no Cargados");
      }
    }  
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error Cargando Parametros");
    }
  }
}
```